# Azure Databricks Concurrent Job -Avoid Consuming the same eventhub messages in all Jobs

Tags: scala, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

Please help us to implement the partition/grouping when receiving eventhub messages in a Azure Databricks concurrent Job and the right approach to consume eventhub messages in a concurrent job.

Created 3 concurrent jobs in Azure Databricks uploading consumer code written in scala as a jar files. In this case receiving the same messages in all 3 concurrent jobs.  To overcome from this issue tried to consume the events by partitioning but receiving the same messages in all 3 partitions.

And also tried by sending messages based on partition key and also tried creating a  consumer groups in eventhubs even though receiving same messages in all the groups. We are not sure to handle the eventhub messages in the concurrent job

EventHub Configuration:

No.of partitions is 3 and  Message Retention is 1
EventHub Producer: Sending messages to Eventhub using .NET (C#) is working fine.
EventHub Consumer: Able to receive messages through Scala Program without any issues.

Problem : Created 3 concurrent jobs in Azure Databricks uploading consumer code written in Scala as a jar files.In this case receiving the same messages in all 3 concurrent jobs.  To overcome from this issue tried to consume the events by partitioning but receiving the same messages in all 3 partitions.And
also tried by sending messages based on partition key and also tried creating a  consumer groups in eventhubs even though receiving same messages in all the groups. We are not sure to handle the eventhub messages in the concurrent job.

Producer C# Code:

```
string eventHubName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eventHubname"];
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eventHubconnectionstring"];
eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubName);

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {       
        var sender = "event hub message 1"  + i;
        var data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sender));
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {sender}");
        eventHubClient.SendAsync(data);
    }
eventHubClient.CloseAsync();
Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Consumer Scala Code:

```
object ReadEvents {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("eventhub")
    .getOrCreate()
  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val connectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder("ConnectionString").setEventHubName("eventhub1").build
    val positions = Map(new NameAndPartition("eventhub1", 0) -> EventPosition.fromStartOfStream)
    val position2 = Map(new NameAndPartition("eventhub1", 1) -> EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(Instant.now()))
    val position3 = Map(new NameAndPartition("eventhub1", 2) -> EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(Instant.now()))

    val ehConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString).setStartingPositions(positions)
    val ehConf2 = EventHubsConf(connectionString).setStartingPositions(position2)
    val ehConf3 = EventHubsConf(connectionString).setStartingPositions(position3)
    val stream = org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ehConf)
    println("Before the loop")
    stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
          rdd.collect().foreach(rec => {
        println(String.format("Message is first stream ===>: %s", new String(rec.getBytes(), Charset.defaultCharset())))
         })
    })
    val stream2 = org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ehConf2)
        stream2.foreachRDD(rdd2 => {
          rdd2.collect().foreach(rec2 => {
    println(String.format("Message  second stream is ===>: %s", new String(rec2.getBytes(), Charset.defaultCharset())))

      })
    })
    val stream3 = org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ehConf)
     stream3.foreachRDD(rdd3 => {
      println("Inside 3rd stream foreach loop")
      rdd3.collect().foreach(rec3 => {
        println(String.format("Message is third stream ===>: %s", new String(rec3.getBytes(), Charset.defaultCharset())))

      })
    })
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

Expecting to partition the eventhub messages properly when receiving it on   concurrent jobs running using scala program.

Answer (score 0):

Below code help to iterate through all partions

```
  eventHubsStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    rdd.foreach { message =>
      if (message != null) {
        callYouMethod(new String(message.getBytes()))

      }
    }
  }
```